# svn tortoise and scplugin

Tags: windows, svn, macos, directory

i've encountered some problems which i can't resolve. Any help is really appreciated.

my customer uses mac and pc.
tortoise on pc, scplugin on mac.

when mac creates new directory, adds it to repository and commits it pc user can't update to the new version. The error is "Can't create directory /.svn. The System can't find the path"

when pc creates the directory, mac can update without problems. so i think that mac is messing around.

I don't know how to solve it.

Thank you for any advices.
Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added .svn to the global-ignores section of the scplugin config file

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like someone is trying to add or commit the `.svn` directory to the repository.  Make sure this directory is not in the repository.